# Please retry. This notice UUID is still being processed

Tags: airbrake

I have a free account on airbrake. and I am also getting the same message. while submitting the error to airbrake i got this message in logger.

[Airbrake] Success: Net::HTTPOK [Airbrake] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.8.7] [Rails: 3.0.10] [Env: development] ** [Airbrake] Response from Airbrake: 7980204c-f28f-8966-9662-265e20dec9fa
http://airbrake.io/locate/7980204c-f28f-8966-9662-265e20dec9fa

when i try to access the url it gives the message "Please retry. This notice UUID is still being processed"

but i don't know why the error are not coming to my account.

Can some body explain why is happening.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AirBrake is undergoing some technical difficulties that are affecting some of our users.

We are working hard on generating a solution to fix the issue.

Thank you for your patience!

From,
Morgan

email: morgan@airbrake.io